# Back stack page name printing null as an initial value in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have three composable in my sample app and I am navigating through each of them one by one.

When I am trying to print the backstack data in navigation controller, I am always getting null as the initial value.

Snippet used to print backstack printing

```
 private fun logBackStack(controller: NavController) {
val backStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry? = controller.previousBackStackEntry
if (backStackEntry != null) {
    val backStackNames = controller
        .currentBackStack.value
        .map { it.destination.route }
        .joinToString(", ")
    Log.d("BackStackLog", "Back stack: $backStackNames")
}
```

}

the result I am getting in log is attached as image, Can anyone help me find out, why a null value is attaching in the navigaton back stack trace.
[image]